# Hybrid angular app throwing error "'./app.module.ajs.js' does not provide an export named 'default'"

Tags: angularjs, angular, module, default, ng-upgrade

I am attempting to convert my AngularJS project to run as a hybrid (i.e. 1.x alongside 2+) following the bootstrapping steps provided at the [angular.io guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#bootstrapping-hybrid-applications) page provided specifically for the task. I have followed the guide with some modifications (primarily just so that I could maintain my existing project structure). My steps in inexact order have been to

- include webpack
- convert my original `app.module.js` and all angular modules declared therein to exportable ES modules

  - (`app.module.js` became `app.module.ajs.ts`, which is transpiled to .js)
- add a new app.module.ts for manual bootstrapping, as per the docs (looks identical to the file of the same name in the docs) and remove the `ng-app` directive from the html as it is no longer necessary
- import the modules into all dependent controller, direcive and service files.

Now when I serve the project, which I believe is the step I should be on (the steps seemed pretty straightforward...) I get a slew of the same error:

[image: 'app.module.ajs.js' does not provide an export named 'default']

However when I open that file up, I do actually see `exports.default = ariaApp`.
Also, the .ts file by the same name does indeed contain the declaration and the default export

```
const ariaApp = angular.module("ariaApp", []) 
export default ariaApp;
```

Has anyone seen this before? / Does anyone know what this error indicates? It seems totally off... All suggestions appreciated! Thank you!!